# TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable - When trying to convert a string to a list

Tags: python, oop

My code is as follows down below. However the x that I input into this function is not int data type, it should be a string. The other code will show you where the input comes from.

```
def validExpression(x):
  x_array = list(x)
  operators = {"+","-","*","/"}
  nums = {"0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"}
  if x_array[0] != "(":
      return 1
  elif x_array[len(x_array)-1] != ")":
      return 1
  count = 1
  front_b_count = 1
  back_b_count = 1
  op_count = 0
  while count < (len(x_array)-2):
      if x_array[count] == "(":
          front_b_count += 1
          count += 1
      if x_array[count] == ")":
          back_b_count += 1
          count += 1
      if x_array[count] in nums:
          count += 1
      if x_array[count] in operators:
          op_count += 1
          count += 1
  if front_b_count != back_b_count:
      return 1
  if op_count > front_b_count:
      return 2
  if op_count < front_b_count:
      return 3
  else:
      return 4
```

The input for the function comes from this segment

```
expression = input("Please enter an expression: ")
    check = validExpression(expression)
```

So an input for expression would be something like (3+1) for example.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: No error with your sample input of `(3+1)`

Comment: Ahh sorry, this is part of my assessment for uni. I've done my assessment in VS code and then uploaded it to codio, was accidently running it through python2, instead of python3